# Updated apt-transport-https, now `sudo apt-get update` doesn't return any information

Tags: raspbian, apt, dpkg

I attempted to run `sudo apt-get update`, but got the error `E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.` Following to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/263803/63810), I checked `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and found no https sources. I tried `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https` and received an error about not being able to connect to the update server or repository. (I lost the exact error text when I rebooted the pi.)

At this point, `apt-get` appeared rather broken, so in following the answer, I downloaded the `apt-transport-https.deb` directly and (after verifying the sha256 checksum) installed via `dpkg -i`. I had one dependency to update, so I also installed `libapt-pkg4.12` (confirming checksum, etc.), which then allowed `apt-transport-https` to complete installation.

Unfortunately, running `sudo apt-get update` produced no output after the manual dpkg install. I tried a `sudo shutdown -r now` and after logging in again, still no output.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

What did I do wrong, and can it be fixed? I'm just looking to use `apt-get update`...

Comment: not sure why you felt the need to install https transport, since the method driver not found is `http` not `https` - repeat what you did for `apt-transport-https.deb` but get `apt.deb` instead ... i.e. you probably want `/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.4.9_armhf.deb`

Comment: I downloaded the apt binary referenced (https://packages.debian.org/jessie/armhf/apt/download) and it didn't solve the issue. `sudo apt update` still returns no feedback.

Comment: try starting from raspberry pi step 1 - creating image on SD card

Comment: That's not really helpful. I'm aware I can scrap the install and start over. There are enough customizations I've done that I'd prefer to *not* have to start over. Being that I'm aware of that and have already considered it as a last ditch effort, I'll try some less destructive methods first...

Comment: You've been quiet for 11 weeks ... and the only thing you tried is to install jessie version of apt a) I didn't realise you were using such an old OS, b) did you download from RASPBIAN repo, or DEBIAN?

Comment: @JaromandaX, you're a genius ... or at least attentive to detail. Thanks for pointing out that I manually installed from the *debian* repos, instead of the *raspian* repos.

Comment: You can add an answer if you want and I'll accept, or I'll write my own postmortem and accept that.

Comment: Please write an answer - you know far more details of the problem and solution than I do

Comment: Slightly off-topic, is there an expected lifespan for the raspian releases? I usually use LTS where possible, since this is a hobby and - as you pointed out - I don't have an over-abundance of time to devote to the matter....

Comment: not sure how long Jessie will be supported, since that's Debian 8, Stretch is Debian 9, and Buster, Debian 10 is about to be released - so, I'd be looking at getting up to Stretch (Debian 9) sooner rather than later - it's a big jump, I'll warn you - what with `systemd`

Comment: Thanks, I've used some `systemd` in a professional context. I'll update my answer to comment on upgrading as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jarmanda X [commented](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93915/updated-apt-transport-https-now-sudo-apt-get-update-doesnt-return-any-inform?noredirect=1#comment151934_93915), I had installed the https, unnecessarily. Then, from a different [comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93915/updated-apt-transport-https-now-sudo-apt-get-update-doesnt-return-any-inform?noredirect=1#comment158583_93915), I realized I had installed the debian packages, ***not*** the raspbian packages.

To fix, I installed the libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.9.8.5_armhf.deb package first (dependency), and then the libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.9.8.5_armhf.deb package from [here](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/).

A quick test of `apt update` showed a permissions error instead of `Illegal instruction`, and one `sudo !!` later and we were in business.

Edit to add: Per discussion, it looks like Jessie is more out of date than I realized and an upgrade is in order.